# How to find the LIST_ID of user created list on Foursquare

Tags: api, foursquare

If you look on this page https://foursquare.com/griekenlandnet you will see there are 55 tips in total, but there are also some user created lists. I can get everything at once through the api explorer on the foursquare site, but I would also like to be able to just get the content for 1 specific list.

According the docs at https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/lists/lists you can request them through this foursquare domain v2/lists/LIST_ID, the problem is that I can't find a way to get the LIST_ID.

Any tips on how to find the list_id? I can get the user_id, but not sure how that helps to get the list_id?

(I would have loved to include more urls, but not allowed to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the userId, you can find the user's lists (and their IDs) via [/users/USER_ID/lists](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/lists.html)

Answer (score 0):

the matter is that you need to be authenticated to get results from `/users/USER_ID/lists...`